При попытке запустить код Телеграм бота на Java появляютя ошибки
Смотрите у меня есть два файла:
Main.java
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bOT bot = new bOT("BOT_TOKEN", "BOT_NICK");
    }
}

и
bOT.java
package org.example;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.ParseMode;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class bOT extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private String botToken;
    private String botName;

    public bOT(String botToken, String botName) {
        this.botToken = botToken;
        this.botName = botName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String msg_from_usr = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            SendMessage msg_from_bot = new SendMessage();
            msg_from_bot.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));

            if (msg_from_usr.equals("/start".toLowerCase())) {
                msg_from_bot.setParseMode(ParseMode.HTML);
                msg_from_bot.setText("<b>Привет!</b>");

                try {
                    execute(msg_from_bot);  // Отправляем сообщение
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return botToken;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botName;
    }
}

Когда я запускаю у меня появлются такие ошибки:
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2205)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3957)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4875)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4881)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:550)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:887)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:808)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:285)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContext.getInstance(ApiContext.java:25)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:30)
    at org.example.bOT.<init>(bOT.java:14)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.getProtectionDomain(FastClass.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:206)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:252)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:158)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @954b04f
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:388)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:364)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:312)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:203)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:197)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:42)
    ... 36 more


Eng SO: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass, Eclipse 2021-06: ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module и т.д.

Этот вопрос похож на: Выдает ошибку при запуске телеграм бота. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

@NowhereMan Да спасибо помогло, надо было более новую версию telegrambots поставить в mvn.
